# search and replace xml error using xslt2

Tags: xslt-2.0

Given the following input xml file, i need to search for values, and replace them in the input xml

the search for values are in the xslt, each row must be replaced by its equivalent row.

```
<TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      <description>2ος Όροφος</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <description>2ος όροφος</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk113">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk115">
      <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk116">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   </catalog>
</DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx">

    <xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string">2ος Όροφος
2ος όροφος</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="replacement-text" as="xs:string">2ος όροφoς
2ος όροφoς</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($search-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($replacement-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="xs:string" select="$replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

i get the errors.

How could the above be altered, so as to keep all the code the xslt has, but avoid the following error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      Error on line 30 
  XTTE0570: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable
  $matched-term ("^2ος όροφος$", "^2ος όροφος$") 
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]/book[1]/description[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]/book[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]
  in built-in template rule
```

live here:
http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5wd

Also i would appreciate an xslt, where the search and replace values could be loaded in external files. ie search.txt, replace.txt

Comment: Well, to help you fix that code we first need to understand what you want to achieve, what should happen if there is more than one match found? The code you have assumes any match will exactly find one item but you seem to have two similar or equal items that match. You can of course type the variable as `as="xs:string*"` to allow more than one item but it is not clear whether that fix does more than avoid the error message.

Comment: i am not sure i understand. all i wanted to do, is replace martin with Martin, and maRtin with Martin for exampe. The value found in the first row of the search-text should be replaced by the value found in the first row of the replacement-text, the value found in the second row of the search-text should be replaced by the value found in the second row of the replacement-text, and so on. Better yet, if those values were read by external files

Comment: As the regular expression match in the code you have shown already uses the `i` flag for case-insensitive search and uses the `lower-case` function to normalize the search terms, the search terms should not contain both `martin` and `maRtin`, but rather only one term for that word. Or drop the use of `lower-case` and of the `i` flag if you present exact search terms to match exactly with the data text.

Comment: thank you, could you please provide me with an xslt example, of how to use two external files for this kind of operations?

Comment: Use `<xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($searchFile)"/>` with `<xsl:param name="searchFile" as="xs:string">search-terms.txt</xsl:param>` and do the same for the replacement.

Comment: Great, worked like a charm, too bad  i cannot vote for your comment, thank you very much

Comment: I have morphed the comments into an answer so you can mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code assumes any search term is entered once and is the converted by the XSLT to lower case in `<xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>`. Furthermore the matching of input data with the search terms in `some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')` is done using the `i` flag to use case-insensitive matching. Your two terms `2ος Όροφος` and `2ος όροφος` differ only in the case of characters so they both result in a match of the input data. As the variable storing the match is type as `xs:string` expecting only a single match you get that error.

To fix that you should either make sure your search terms contain a certain term only once or you need to remove the use of `lower-case` and the `i` flag.

As for using text files with the search and replacement list, XSLT 2 and later supports the XPath 2 and later `unparsed-text(file-uri, optional-encoding)` function you can use as in

```
<xsl:param name="searchFile" as="xs:string">search-terms.txt</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text($searchFile)"/>
```

to load the terms from a text file.